# How to convert large binary file into pickle dictionary in python?

Tags: python-3.x, pickle, fasttext

I am trying to convert large binary file contains Arabic words with 300 dimension vectors into pickle dictionary

What I am write so far is:

```
import pickle
ArabicDict = {}
with open('cc.ar.300.bin', encoding='utf-8') as lex:
    for token in lex:
         for line in lex.readlines():
             data = line.split()
             ArabicDict[data[0]] = float(data[1])

pickle.dump(ArabicDict,open("ArabicDictionary.p","wb"))
```

The error which I am getting is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:\Dataset", line 4, in <module>
    for token in lex:
  File "E:\lib\codecs.py", line 321, in decode
    (result, consumed) = self._buffer_decode(data, self.errors, final)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xba in position 0: invalid start byte
```

Comment: So what's your question? Do you get an error? If so, what's the full traceback? If not, what happened that you didn't expect, and what did you expect to happen instead?

Comment: Note: if `lex` is the fileobject, then `for token in lex` will already get each line. You don't need to then use `for line in lex.readlines():`, this will read the *rest of the file into memory*.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I edited my question. The error I am getting is                   
 for token in lex:
  File "E:\lib\codecs.py", line 321, in decode
    (result, consumed) = self._buffer_decode(data, self.errors, final)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xba in position 0: invalid start byte